# C++: Displaying suits and ranks in card game

Tags: c++

I'm having issues printing the card suits and ranks when I try to show the players hand. I can't seem to figure out how to do it correctly. Any hints would be helpful. Here are snips of my code

```
const string RANKS[] = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
const string SUITS[] = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
```

and

```
void showHand(vector<int> &deck) {
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << "Player " << i + 1 << ": ";
        for (int k = 0; k < 13; k++) {
            cout << card[k][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

In this case, this only prints the integer values of the cards but not the corresponding suits and ranks. How can I display them?

Comment: What type is card?

Comment: How are you storing both card and suite in a single integer? (It can be done, but I doubt that's what you are currently doing)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need some transformation of the card index to the two rank and suit indizes, like two functions

```
int suit_index(int card_index){
    return card_index / 13;
}

int rank_index(int card_index){
    return card_index % 13;
}
```

Given this, the print within the innermost loop that is currently "cout << card[k][i] << " ";" becomes

```
card = card[k][i];
suit = suit_index(card);
rank = rank_index(card);
cout << RANKS[rank] << " of " << SUITS[suit] << " ";
```

(or you go directly with suit = card / 13; etc, just wanted to have placeholders if your transformation is different)

Comment: You're assuming card is 0-51 (which is probably is, but we don't know for sure).

Comment: @Colin__s Nah, I'm just giving an example how it can be done. That said, I'd say them having those values is quite likely, so yeah, why not assume it. If it's not like this, he'll comment, if it is, he's got an answer. Better than doing a game of question-answer ping pong.

Comment: That said, @deaddeaddeads, Colin is totally right about us being in the dark being a bad thing. You should make it clear how a value of card is to be understood. If it has to be minimalistic, at least with something like a comment about the value, but better would be something like enum Ranks{ ace, two, ... } to replace non-informative int-values with meaning and then something like structure card{Rank rank; Suit suit;}. Does not have to be exactly like this, but do something to bring meaning in it, so that at any time you know exactly how card is structured. Good for readability.

Comment: Or structure card{int rank; Suit suit;} if you want to emphasize the order (although you have Ace coming first, which means that you have to do some more complex comparison anyway when it comes to see if one card beats another